# Cannot create a file or folder named * on a mounted disk

Tags: automount

version：Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Cannot create a file or folder named * on a mounted disk，but can create it on system disk

Comment: You should name your files better. You won't remember what that file is for in six months.

Answer (score 4):

When you use a filesystem you need to follow the rules of that filesystem.

Linux for instance differentiates between small and capital letters (a and A are different characters). Linux allows (almost?) anything to be part of a filename (even "enter" or "tab" are allowed). These characters should be -avoided-: `/` `>` `|` `:` `&` but you can use them. Those characters all have special meanings but the advice is to avoid them so it is possible to use them (and you can expect commands where you parse the filename to act abnormally compared to when not using them).

Other filesystems have different rules and often do not accept characters. [Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file) has a list of characters that are actively blocked and that includes the `*` so you probably are using a Windows filesystem on that partition.